# how to select rows with repeated occurrences of given value in the index column?

Tags: r

I am trying to select rows with repeated appearances of `index` and only if amount data changes sign.

```
> df
   index amount
1     a      1
2     b      2
3     b      3
4     c      1
5     c     -1
```

Given the simple df above.  I would like the returned df to have only row 4 and 5.

What would be a simple way of filtering?

Answer (score 1):

One option is `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'index', `if` the number of `unique` `sign` of 'amount' is greater than 1, then get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(sign(amount))>1) .SD , by = index]
#     index amount
#1:     c      1
#2:     c     -1
```

---

A `base R`  option would be with `ave`

```
i1 <- with(df, as.logical(ave(sign(amount), index, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))>1)))
df[i1,]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  That works for me quite well

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option with `dplyr` :

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(index) %>%
  filter(length(unique(sign(amount))) > 1) 
#> Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#> Groups: index [1]
#> 
#>   index amount
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1     c      1
#> 2     c     -1
```